# rationalize denominator for perturbation theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, rationalising-denominator

I need to extract terms in equation which are multiplied with degrees of $a$, $a$ is constant:

$$a\frac{1}{r_0+a r_1+a^2 r_2+a^3 r_3} \cdot \frac{\partial (x_0+ax_1+a^2 x_2+a^3 x_3)}{\partial y}$$

With perturbation methods I will extract terms next to $a^0$ and with some other equation that will be solution of my system for zero approximation, everything next to $a^1$ will be solution for first approximation...

But I don`t know how to extract these terms in denominator with variables $r$. I have solution for this example, 
for zero approximation-everything(every term) which is multiplied with $a^0$ result is $0$-there are no such terms.

For the first approximation-everything multiplied with $a$ (every term next to $a$-but only this degree of $a$) is one term: $\dfrac{1}{r_0} \dfrac{\partial x_0}{\partial y}$.

I tried with first fraction to use binomial series, but it is not correct results with given solution which I have,

Comment: You can write $2\cdot3\cdot4$ or $2\times3\times4,$ but an asterisk, as in $2*3*4$ is a workaround for occasions when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard.

Comment: If $a$ is a small parameter, you can use a Taylor series around $r_0$ to approximate $1/(r_0+ar_1+\ldots)$.